# How to apply background image on headerBuilder inside ExpansionPanel - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, expansion

I am trying to style `ExpansionPanel` which is inside `ExpansionPanelList` in Flutter but the background image is not applying to the whole header area of the panel.

I want to apply background image on the `headerbuilder` of expansionPanel.

Currenlty I'm trying to do it with the help of stack and giving background image to it. Doing this, Image is covering most of the header builder area but not covering area below arrow of `expansionPanel`.

**I want the background image to also cover area underneath arrow of the expansion panel.** How can I do that?

```dart
ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) { // Some code  },
      children: _items.map((MyItem _item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, 
// Want to add the picture in the background of 
// header builder
          headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
            return Stack(
                children: [
                  // >>>>>>>>>>>>>> Image
                  Container(
                    child: Image.network(
                      _item.prodCtgData
                          .pic,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // >>>>>>>>>>>>>> Text
                  Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text("Data"),
                  ),
                ],
         
            );
          },
          isExpanded: _item.isExpanded,
          body: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics:
                NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            children:[
              //Some data
            ]
                
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
```

[image]